# from a web server detecting if 2 machines are on the same gateway ipv6

Tags: ip, ipv6

From a webserver, what ways, if any, can be used to detect if 2 client machines are behind the same gateway as each other?

For example if both machines are behind NAT they'll have the same IP address from the POV of the server. As of IPv6 though NAT seems less common.

Can I mostly assume if the top 64 bits of an IPv6 address are the same they're behind the same gateway?

**NOTE** I'm not looking for a perfect solution which is why I asked "mostly". I'm looking for a 99% solution. Ideally for home users, not corp. 99.999% of home users are on a router that's using NAT so that works for IPv4. Is there a solution for IPv6 that will also mostly be true?

Comment: Not really. You can determine that they are probably on the same network that way, but a network can have multiple routers servicing it, and devices on the network can have different gateways, even with IPv4 (not everything on IPv4 uses NAT). Routers are meant to be transparent at layer-3.

Comment: I'm not looking for a perfect solution which is why I asked "mostly". I'm looking for a 99% solution. Ideally for home users, not corp. 99.999% of home users are on a router that's using NAT so that works for IPv4. Is there a solution for IPv6 that will also *mostly* be true?

Comment: As I wrote, you can determine the subnet that way, to a high degree of probability. Where you are going to fail is when the ISP delegates a shorter prefix, and the site (home or business) uses multiple subnets. This will become more common. IANA tried to force the ISPs to assign `/48` to everyone, giving everyone 65,536 subnets, but the ISPs fought back, and many assign `/56` or `/60` prefixes to home users. That means that most home users have at least 16 subnets to use. My ISP gave me a `/48` prefix, and I have quite a few subnets that I use.

Comment: Also, unlike IPv4, IPv6 allows you to assign a bunch of networks to interfaces. My PC has several, and different traffic is sent on different subnets from the same PC on the same interface.

Comment: Maybe I'm asking the question wrong. The problem I'm trying to solve is figuring out if 2 machines should talk to each other without the users having to enter any info. Up until now I've checked if they are on the same ipv4 address which means they're both behind the same NAT box. This has work in nearly all homes. Now I need to do the same in IPv6 somehow. Mom goes to "connect2family.eg", Dad goes to "connect2family.eg". connect2family.eg sees they are both from the same ipv4 IP address and automatically connects them to each other. Is there a creative way to do the same on ipv6?

Comment: That seems like it will be more and more problematic as time goes by. It's likely homes will get multiple subnets, e.g. Dad's den, IoT devices, entertainment, kids, etc. this allows separate access levels/parental controls for each subnet.